# Overfetching with cache-first policy

Tags: apollo-client

Here's the scenario:

1. I query a list of Invoices via a query that uses 2 variables (companyId:1 and clientId:1) and it returns 10 Invoices.  I use fetch-policy: cache-first
2. I create a new Invoice for (companyId:1, clientId:2) that returns the corresponding Invoice entity.
3. I re-issue the query in step #1 - but I'm getting back 11 Invoices.  It includes the new Invoice created for clientId:2.

I guess the problem is that there's no link between the query variables and the cache - so it can't possibly work.  In other words I'm requesting query variable {clientId:1} - but the cache is stored as follows (i.e., no use of the query variable filter "clientId".

```
Invoice:319
  id:"319"
  __typename:"Invoice"
 invoiceDate:"2021-05-25"
 invoiceAmount:650
 __ref:"Client:1"
```

Is it not possible to use the cache this way? Do I need to do a refetch after the mutation rather than just returning the Invoice entity data?  Or is there something else I can do?

Here's the query for step #1 that returns the Invoices (and other Entities):

```
query BillPay($companyId: ID!, $clientId: ID!) {
    client(options: { companyId: $companyId, clientId: $clientId }) {
      id
      displayName
    }
    payments(options: { companyId: $companyId, clientId: $clientId }) {
      id
      paymentDate
      paymentAmount
      reference
      client {
        id
      }
    }
    invoices(options: { companyId: $companyId, clientId: $clientId }) {
      id
      invoiceDate
      invoiceAmount
      client {
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the response from the mutation

```
fragment InvoiceResponse on Invoice {
    id
    invoiceDate
    invoiceAmount
    client {
      id
      displayName
      colorNumber
    }
  }
```

Comment: Cache in Apollo is created by normalizing the response received . It does not take the query variables in consideration . This might help https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/caching/demystifying-cache-normalization/

Comment: Thanks Shyman.  In addition to storing the normalized response, the cache contains the list of queries and their variables.  So, if I make two cache-first queries with different variables - say client 1 and then client 2 - Apollo handles this correctly and I get the separate return data. Problems occur with a create mutation - say for client 3.  If I just return the mutated data, it's put into the cache - but is not available for future queries.  If I do a cache modify - then the new client 3 data also gets returned in future cache-first queries for client 1 and 2 - is this known behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that query results using cache-only fetch policy are not reliable after a mutation.  Mutations that update the cache will update all cached queries.  It means that you may get results that should not be included based on the query variables - so you will need to programmatically filter the results to make sure you don't have data you don't want.

Here's my communication with the Apollo team on this:

From me:

> OK.  So just to confirm, if I’ve done a mutation, my cache-only
> queries with variables might contain data that is incorrect based on
> the variables - so I need to filter the result set to remove the
> incorrect data. I wonder if that’s common knowledge.

From Apollo:

> Correct you should filter the result set to remove the incorrect data.
> This is not common knowledge but it is good feedback for team to add
> in our documentation.